# Handling when CLPlacemark property is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label that displays the street name that belongs to an exact geo location. I'm retrieving the street name from the `placemarkStreet` variable, that works correctly, however sometimes when I log `placemark.thoroughfare` it's a `(null)` on the console. I know it's because it's a `nil`, but I can't write a proper if statement to handle the situation when it's a `nil`. Basically none of the below if statements works when the value is nil, so I would really appreciate if somebody could show me the right way how can I handle this.

```
 [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Finding address");

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);

  } else {

  CLPlacemark *placemarkStreet = [placemarks lastObject];

  NSLog(@"placemark %@", placemarkStreet.thoroughfare);

// 1. attempt
  if ([placemarkStreet.thoroughfare isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {

// do something
      }

// 2. attempt
  if (!placemarkStreet.thoroughfare) {

// do something
      }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first attempt won't work, as your are calling a method on `nil` which will *always* return false / 0 / nil. `@"(null)"` is just how `NSLog` represents a `nil` value.

The second attempt should work - it is equivalent to

```
if (placemarkStreet.thoroughfare == nil) {
```

Comment: You are right, now it works. Maybe I just mixed up something when I tried the 2. variation. Thanks, I didn't know that @"(null)" is nil in NSLog.